# Construct an assignment matrix - Python

Tags: python, matrix, variable-assignment

I have two lists of element

```
a = [1,2,3,2,3,1,1,1,1,1]
b = [3,1,2,1,2,3,3,3,3,3]
```

and I am trying to uniquely match the element from a to b, my expected result is like this:

```
1: 3
2: 1
3: 2
```

So I tried to construct an assignment matrix and then use `scipy.linear_sum_assignment`

```
a = [1,2,3,2,3,1,1,1,1,1]
b = [3,1,2,1,2,3,3,3,3,3]

total_true = np.unique(a)
total_pred = np.unique(b)

matrix = np.zeros(shape=(len(total_pred),
                         len(total_true)
                         )
                  )

for n, i in enumerate(total_true):
    for m, j in enumerate(total_pred):
        matrix[n, m] = sum(1 for item in b if item==(i))
```

I expected the matrix to be:

```
  1 2 3
1 0 2 0
2 0 0 2
3 6 0 0
```

But the output is:

```
[[2. 2. 2.]
 [2. 2. 2.]
 [6. 6. 6.]]
```

What mistake did I made in here? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This row:

```
matrix[n, m] = sum(1 for item in b if item==(i))
```

counts the occurrences of `i` in `b` and saves the result to `matrix[n, m]`. Each cell of the matrix will contain either the number of 1's in `b` (i.e. 2) or the number of 2's in `b` (i.e. 2) or the number of 3's in `b` (i.e. 6). Notice that this value is completely independent of `j`, which means that the values in one row will always be the same.

In order to take `j` into consideration, try to replace the row with:

```
matrix[n, m] = sum(1 for x, y in zip(a, b) if (x, y) == (j, i))
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need to process this by `Pandas`. try to use `zip` and `dict`:

```
In [42]: a = [1,2,3,2,3,1,1,1,1,1]
    ...: b = [3,1,2,1,2,3,3,3,3,3]
    ...: 

In [43]: c =zip(a,b)

In [44]: dict(c)
Out[44]: {1: 3, 2: 1, 3: 2}
```

**UPDATE** as OP said, if we need to store all the value with the same key, we can use `defaultdict`:

```
In [58]: from collections import defaultdict

In [59]: d = defaultdict(list)

In [60]: for k,v in c:
    ...:     d[k].append(v)
    ...:     

In [61]: d
Out[61]: defaultdict(list, {1: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], 2: [1, 1], 3: [2, 2]})
```

Comment: this works correctly in this example because it's already perfectly matched. If I used a more complicated list (not perfect matching), sometimes the elements will not be uniquely matched (one element in a match to 2 or more elements in b)

Comment: @ThanhNguyen I not sure I understand you, but if you want me to help you, just show your expect output for more detail.

Comment: This is the result on my data:

{1.0: array([34]),
 2.0: array([32]),
 3.0: array([32]),
 4.0: array([16]),
 5.0: array([21]),
 6.0: array([30]),
 7.0: array([1]),
 8.0: array([13]),
 9.0: array([31]),
 10.0: array([6]),
 11.0: array([21]),
 12.0: array([40]),
 13.0: array([40]),
 14.0: array([36])}

. As you can see, the 2, 3 is both matched to 32, and 12, 13 is both matched to 40.

Because my list is very long, so I put a toy example in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In case your expected output, since how we specify the matrix as `a(i, j)` with `i` is the index of the row, and `j` is the index of the col. Looking at `a(3,1)` in your matrix, the result is `6`, which means (3,1) combination matches 6 times, with 3 is from b and 1 is from a. We can find all the matches from 2 list.

```
matches = [tuple([x, y]) for x,y in zip(b, a)]
```

Then we can find how many matches there are of a specific combination, for example a(3, 1).

```
result = matches.count((3,1))
```